# Logging in using AD

Tags: sql-server, azure, active-directory

I wonder whether it's possible to login to a SQL server instance hosted at Azure using Active Directory credentials.

If this is possible, how?

Comment: Logging in to what? I don't want to start an edit war but I don't see the value-add of this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Its not possible as of date 02-27-2014

Comment: I'll have to accept this as true then: "Poul Kjeldager Sørensen is the Windows Azure Lead at Composite A/S leading the development of their Composite Windows Azure Webrole."

Comment: :D haha, i am right until someone prove me wrong ;)

Comment: I'd love to see that ;)